# VS 2015 Diagnostic Tools dont jumping to source code C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2015

I need to track memory leak. But when I make snapshot to see the difference, I can't jump to source code from Allocation Call Stack.
Allocation call stack don't show code line and do nothing when dbl-clicking.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, this functionality only in enterprise version :(